# Can not Migrate files

Tags: react-native, androidx

I have a message when running (react-native run-android )telling (Failed to run jetifier. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.)

I tried everything to solve this issue but still not solved and Couldn't migrate my files
android version :  23 and 29

it's came suddenly everything was working well and then suddenly when I refreshed the emulator it's stopped and started this